# How do I add a random number to a Stored variable at the results as a number, not 2 strings added together?

Tags: javascript

So here is a dorky experiment I put together basically trying to generate a D&D style attack roll with a modifier. I want to add the numbers, but javascript keeps adding the numbers as strings. I'm not sure how to get the basic math done..... Here is my code-

```
        function battle()
    {
        var CS = document.battleForm.playerCS.value;
        var D20 =  Math.ceil(Math.round(Math.random() * 20))
        var attackRoll = CS + D20

        if (isNaN(CS))
        {
            alert ("please provide your Combat Score!")
            return
        }
        if (CS != '')
        {
            document.battleForm.enemyCS.value = attackRoll 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CS` is a string; use `parseFloat` or unary plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure two numbers are added together, try:

```
var num3 = +num1 + (+num2);
```

This *could* be preferred over the use of `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for two reasons:

- `+` will convert any number (meaning, you don't need a different method for an integer and a float)
- `+` will fail if either value are not convertible. `parseInt` and `parseFloat` ignore any trailing text in the variable. So for example, `parseInt("10px", 10)` results in `10`, while `(+"10px")` results in `NaN`.

It's up to you what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
var CS = parseInt(document.battleForm.playerCS.value, 10); // or parseFloat if you expect float number
```

The value of any form text is a string, so you need to convert it to number.